# Magento : Can't rewrite Widget Grid for optimize filtering

Tags: php, xml, magento, shopping-cart

I working on [Magento](http://magentocommerce.com/) framework.

I want to rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` to optimize search filtering.

I add rewrite block on my `etc/config.xml` and name block as `grid_search_date`.

```
<config>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <data>Jdate_Format_Helper_Data</data>
        </rewrite>
      </core>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <grid_search_date>
        <rewrite>
          <widget_grid>Jdate_Format_Block_Widget_Grid</widget_grid>
        </rewrite>
      </grid_search_date>
      <topmenu_admin_time>
        <rewrite>
          <widget_grid_column_renderer_date>Jdate_Format_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</widget_grid_column_renderer_date>
        </rewrite>
      </topmenu_admin_time>

    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

You can see `Jdate_Format_Block_Widget_Grid` want to rewrite `widget_grid` and we move to this file

```
class Jdate_Format_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{   
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {   

        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            $field = ( $column->getFilterIndex() ) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
            if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
                call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
            } else {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                die(var_dump($cond["orig_from"]));
                die(var_dump($cond["orig_to"]));
                if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }   
}
```

But nothing happen. But if I change directly `Widget_Grid` file to this, it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<global>
   <blocks>
      <adminhtml>  <!-- should be the name of the module -->
        <rewrite>
          <widget_grid>Jdate_Format_Block_Widget_Grid</widget_grid>
        </rewrite>
      </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
  .....
```